# Access date filter

Tags: date, ms-access

I have a table that lists orders received.

I am running a report, to see how many orders receiver prior to D-Day.
So for example, I would want to see:

```
D Day-5 days: 8 orders received in total 
D Day-4 days: 12 orders received in total 
D Day-3 days: 20 orders received in total 
D Day-2 days: 33 orders received in total 
D Day-1 days: 55 orders received in total
```

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM recipients 
WHERE  
orderDate > #01/01/2017# 
AND orderDate < #10/02/2017#   -- (Where 10/2/17 is already X days prior to D Day)
```

But the query is running and giving me **all orders received to date** (which is 26/2/2017).

The correct answer should be zero (no orders received before the 10th of Feb), but instead - its showing me 200 + records, where i can see that the `orderDate` field is *after* the 10th of Feb.

Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL doesn't expect the format dd/mm/yyyy but mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd for string expression for a date value (which by itself carries no format). Thus, 10/02/2017 is read as 2017-10-02, the second day of October.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM recipients 
WHERE  
orderDate > #01/01/2017# 
AND orderDate < #02/10/2017#
```

or, the generic method as you rarely has fixed date values:

```
PARAMETERS DateFrom DateTime, DateTo DateTime;
SELECT * FROM recipients 
WHERE  
orderDate > DateFrom AND orderDate < DateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed up using the `Format1` function, which seemed to solve the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM recipients 
WHERE  
orderDate > Format (#01/01/2017#,'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND orderDate < Format (#10/02/2017#,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Though I still dont understand fully what was wrong with my initial query. I guess a date format issue: dd/mm or mm/dd

Thanks